# SQL Query for PL/SQL statement won't work

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to execute an SQL statement that I am planning on using with a PL/SQL cursor down the road. It will fetch an employees name and the projects they are working on if they are working on more than 1 project. For some reason, the "having count(pno)>1" stipulation will not work here. It just says "no data found"

Is there anything I'm doing wrong? I included my DB code below the query.

Query:

```
select pname, fname
from project, works_on, employee
where pno=pnumber and essn=ssn
group by pname, fname
having count(pno)>1;
```

Works_on table:

```
create table works_on (
Essn    char(9) not null,
Pno int not null,
hours   decimal(3,1),
primary key(essn, pno),
foreign key(Essn) references employee,
foreign key(pno) references project);
```

Project table:

```
create table project (
Pname varchar2(15) not null,
Pnumber int     not null,
Plocation varchar2(15),
Dnum    int not null,
primary key (Pnumber),
unique (Pname),
foreign key(Dnum) references department(Dnumber));
```

Employee table:

```
 create table employee (
 Fname  varchar2(15) not null,
 Minit  char(1),
 Lname  varchar2(15) not null,
 Ssn    char(9),
 Bdate  date,
 Address    varchar2(30),
 Sex    char(1),
 Salary decimal(10,2),
 super_ssn  char(9),
 dno    int,
 primary key (Ssn),
 foreign key (dno) references department(Dnumber));
```

## EDIT

I managed to make this work instead:

```
select fname, pname
  from employee, works_on, project
  where essn=ssn and pno=pnumber
  group by fname, pname
  having count(pnumber) > 1
```

What made pnumber work in place of pno?

Comment: There is neither a cursor nor PL/SQL in your code - it is entirely SQL. "Is there anything wrong?" How could we possibly tell? Maybe your data is unique on the `pno` column - in which case returning zero rows would be correct for the `HAVING COUNT(pno) > 1` filter.

Comment: My sincere apologies. I edited this to include my tables. Also, this is a regular old SQL statement that will later be included in a PL/SQL cursor. Total oversight by me when writing the question

Comment: I can absolutely edit this to reflect my mistake. Could you remove your downvote if I do this? If of course you were the one to do it.

Comment: @MT0, I seriously feel like an idiot. I was so focused on my problem and what I knew I would later use it for that I posted a very poorly structured question. I hope that my edits have improved it

Comment: The question is still unanswerable since there is no example data which would demonstrate the issue. Try creating a [MCVE] with the DML statements necessary to populate the tables as well as your expected output (and the reasoning why that is expected).

Comment: I'm not sure how including data that populates the table more readable, but I can do it if you would like. Again I appreciate you taking the time to help

Comment: My expected output is a list of Employee First Names and Project names where the employee is working on more than 1 project.

Answer (score 1):

> My expected output is a list of Employee First Names and Project names where the employee is working on more than 1 project.

Something like this:

```
SELECT e.fname, p.projects
FROM   (
  SELECT w.essn,
         LISTAGG( p.pname, ',' ) WITHIN GROUP ( ORDER BY p.pname ) AS projects
  FROM   works_on w
         INNER JOIN
         project p
         ON ( w.pno = p.pnumber )
  GROUP BY w.essn
  HAVING COUNT( DISTINCT w.pno ) > 1
) p
INNER JOIN
employee e
ON ( p.essn = e.ssn )
```

or:

```
SELECT e.fname,
       p.pname
FROM   (
         SELECT w.*,
                COUNT( pno ) OVER ( PARTITION BY essn ) AS num_projects
         FROM   works_on w
       ) w
       INNER JOIN
       employee e
       ON ( e.ssn = w.essn )
       INNER JOIN
       project p
       ON ( w.pno = p.pnumber )
WHERE  w.num_projects > 1
```

Comment: I managed to make this work instead:  select fname, pname
from employee, works_on, project
where essn=ssn and pno=pnumber;
group by fname, pname
having count(pnumber)>1;